# Python link between properties

Tags: python

I wanted to know if there is an easy way to link properties in a object. This is my code :

```py
import numpy as np

obj = {}
obj["data"] = np.linspace(1,10)
obj["first"] = obj["data"][0] # obj["first"] = 1
obj["last"] = obj["data"][-1] # obj["last"] = 10

obj["data"] = np.linspace(20,100)
# obj["first"] = 20
# obj["last"] = 100
```

Is there a way to automatically update the first and last properties when data has changed ? I don't want to set each time obj["first"] and obj["last"].

Comment: You could use: `first, *_, last = obj["data"]`

Comment: With your code it does not set the property first and last automatically

Comment: The question is why set it. If a property can be accessed easily and with minimal cost, unless there is a better benefit for storing it, I would not store it in first place. But it really depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

For this behaviour I would create a simple class with [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```py
import numpy as np


class Ranger:

    data = np.array([])

    @property
    def first(self):
        return self.data[0]

    @property
    def last(self):
        return self.data[-1]


obj = Ranger()
obj.data = np.linspace(1, 10)
print(obj.first, obj.last)
obj.data = np.linspace(20, 100)
print(obj.first, obj.last)
```

Comment: This is awesome. I think though it adds complexity in where simple access exists to first and last. E.g. `first, *_, last = obj["data"]`

Comment: Absolutely, @PraysonW.Daniel, I would consider this unnecessarily complex as well, simple unpacking or indexing does the trick. I just wanted to point towards properties, as the whole wording in the question sounded like Mo0nKizz was not aware of that feature yet.